# Need help on tornado coroutines

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I'm new to python and tornado. I was trying some stuff with coroutines.

```js
def doStuff(callback):
    def task():
        callback("One Second Later")
    Timer(1,task).start()

@gen.coroutine
def routine1():    
    ans = yield gen.Task(doStuff)
    raise gen.Return(ans)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print routine1()
```

I'm trying to get the result of doStuff() function, which I expect to be "One Second Later". But it's not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What's "Timer"? Can I see its source code or can you tell me where Timer is imported from?

Comment: Timer calls the passed function after given time (in Secs) asynchronously.
its present in "threading" package of python.

Comment: Don't mix threading and Tornado unless you really know what you're doing. Do `yield gen.sleep(1)` instead: http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's probably happening is, you haven't started the IOLoop, nor are you waiting for your coroutine to complete before your script exits. You'll probably notice your script runs in a couple milliseconds, rather than pausing for a second as it ought. Do this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
    print IOLoop.instance().run_sync(routine1)
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse for help. But scripts run for around a second. Can it be due to Timer?

Comment: Ah, since the timer thread isn't a daemon, I guess the process waits for the timer thread before it exits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Could you please suggest some books so that i can learn more about tornado?

Comment: There aren't any recent books, but Ben Darnell has improved the documentation tremendously in recent releases, see http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide.html